# jquery ajax not getting json file in my local

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have to bring the data from json file to my html page.
I am using angularjs and jquery for my project. The jquery ajax returning 200 response, but it is not returning the data inside success. I am able to get the data inside error property (XHR.responseText).
The code i have written is(tried inside controller also jquery document ready call),

```
$.ajax({
        url:'../scripts/chart.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(jqXHR) {
            alert(''); *// not entering into success call??*
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR); *//returning the value inside jqXHR.responseText*
  }
});
```

Any help?
I have used latest jquery lib file and json file as follows,

```
{
"sshe": [Srno: "1",
Cluster Id: "1"]
}
```

Anyway i am using CORS plugin in chrome to overcome same origin cross browser issue? any help? Any working sample?

Comment: Use server url e.g. `http://localhost` to load JSON

Comment: Are you opening this from file system? Then the origin is null

Comment: that's not valid json either. check your json in jsonlint.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making json/jsonp xhr requests on the file: protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589714/making-json-jsonp-xhr-requests-on-the-file-protocol)

Comment: what framework you are using? maybe you need to setup the path.... you can access the json using the brower GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{
"sshe": [Srno: "1",
Cluster Id: "1"]
}`

you have a json obj with a top level node of "sshe" and a value of an array [], but the array is not properly formatted.  You could reformat your array as ["Srno","1","Cluster Id","1"] - but due to the way you have it set up I'm guessing you want the array to have 2 objects inside of it and not 4 separate values, if you want the array to hold 2 objects write it as follows :

`{
    "sshe":[
        {"Srno":"1"},
        {"ClusterId":"1"}
    ]
}`

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks all. I am looking only ajax part, now only i realized the issue in json format.